Create a new dataset which displays the 'mean' for each column
I have a dataframe that looks like this:



N
Place
Number
C
H
E
G
D




1
Angus
25
33
45
23
60
43


2
Argyl
43
23
12
56
19
45


3
Ayrsh
14
46
27
92
14
12



and i want to create a function which iterates through 'C', 'H', 'E', 'G', 'D', and creates a new dataframes where the row values are replaced with the mean, eg: meanC = 33/25, meanH = 45/25, meanE = 23/25.
I am not quite sure how to go about it.
Any help would be appreciated, thankyou!

Use df.div on the selected columns, passing df['Number'] and axis=0 (row-wise) and chain df.add_prefix.
cols = ['C', 'H', 'E', 'G', 'D']

df[cols].div(df['Number'], axis=0).add_prefix('mean')

      meanC     meanH     meanE    meanG     meanD
0  1.320000  1.800000  0.920000  2.40000  1.720000
1  0.534884  0.279070  1.302326  0.44186  1.046512
2  3.285714  1.928571  6.571429  1.00000  0.857143


Use df.join to add this to (part?) of the original df:

out = (df[[c for c in df.columns if c not in cols]]
       .join(
           df[cols].div(df['Number'], axis=0).add_prefix('mean')
           )
       )

# or select with `df[df.columns.difference(cols, sort=False)]`

See df.index.difference (thanks to @sammywemmy for  noting sort=False).
Output:
   N  Place  Number     meanC     meanH     meanE    meanG     meanD
0  1  Angus      25  1.320000  1.800000  0.920000  2.40000  1.720000
1  2  Argyl      43  0.534884  0.279070  1.302326  0.44186  1.046512
2  3  Ayrsh      14  3.285714  1.928571  6.571429  1.00000  0.857143


if you add sort=False to your df.columns.difference(cols), it should preserve the order - something like this : df.columns.difference(cols, sort=False)

You have to div on axis=0.
If you want a new DataFrame you can use:
cols = ['C', 'H', 'E', 'G', 'D']

out = (df[cols].div(df['Number'], axis=0)
       .combine_first(df).reindex_like(df)
      )

To modify the input in place:
cols = ['C', 'H', 'E', 'G', 'D']

df[cols] = df[cols].div(df['Number'], axis=0)

Output / modified df:
   N  Place  Number         C         H         E        G         D
0  1  Angus      25  1.320000  1.800000  0.920000  2.40000  1.720000
1  2  Argyl      43  0.534884  0.279070  1.302326  0.44186  1.046512
2  3  Ayrsh      14  3.285714  1.928571  6.571429  1.00000  0.857143


That is Awesome! Thanky you so much :)

if you use a slice, you get more performance (depending on your data size)

The other solutions are fine, this is another option, via assign:
df.assign(**df.loc[:, 'C':].div(df.Number,axis='index'))
   N  Place  Number         C         H         E        G         D
0  1  Angus      25  1.320000  1.800000  0.920000  2.40000  1.720000
1  2  Argyl      43  0.534884  0.279070  1.302326  0.44186  1.046512
2  3  Ayrsh      14  3.285714  1.928571  6.571429  1.00000  0.857143


Yes, this is also nice. I suppose I was mostly focusing on the request to get the prefix "mean" added.
